# Are there any training datasets using standard font text rather than hand written ones?

Tags: datasets, reference-request, resource-request

Are there any training datasets using standard font text rather than handwritten ones?

I tried using the MNIST handwritten one on font based chars, but it didn't work well.

Comment: I mean you can easily make your own on MS Paint? Or are you looking for pictures with noise like tilting or blur or grain with standard fonts (like in post office letters)?

Comment: @DuttaA i guess i was just being lazy. Seems like a lot of work, many different fonts, in the correct format for keras